# Open Excel sheet with OleDbAdaptor and query parameters

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb

This was my previous method for opening an excel sheet:

```
public static System.Data.DataTable GetEntireSheet(string fileName,
    string sheetName)
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString(fileName);
    System.Data.DataTable excelTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
    excelTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    using (OleDbConnection connection =
        new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(
            string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Select * from [{0}$]", sheetName),
            connection))
        {
            adaptor.Fill(excelTable);
        }
    }

    return excelTable;
}
```

This works fine but it also generates code analysis warning:

> CA2100    The query string passed to
>   'OleDbDataAdapter.OleDbDataAdapter(string, OleDbConnection)' in
>   'ExcelWrapper.GetEntireSheet(string, string)' could contain the
>   following variables 'string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
>   "SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", sheetName)'. If any of these variables could
>   come from user input, consider using a stored procedure or a
>   parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string
>   concatenations.

The sheetname is not coming from user input, so I could suppress the warning, but suppressing warnings is a practice I try to avoid as much as possible.

I've tried to update the method with the following:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [?]";
string parameter = string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}$", sheetName);
using (OleDbCommand command =
    new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.BSTR).Value =
        parameter;

    using (OleDbDataAdapter adaptor =
        new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adaptor.Fill(excelTable);
    }
}
```

It looks suspicious, though and it also generates an OleDbException of:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object '?'.
>   Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path
>   name correctly. If '?' is not a local object, check your network
>   connection or contact the server administrator.

What is the right way to call this with query parameters?

Comment: Parameters cannot be used to represent a tablename

Comment: The code analysis tool suggest to avoid user input. This could be done using the GetSchema method to retrieve the tablenames (IE sheet names) then put everything in a combobox where user can only choose the valid names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter to represent a table name (sheet name). You use parameters only when you want to pass VALUES for INSERT, UPDATE and in WHERE clause.

However, as pointed out, by your code analysis tool you can use a white list of table names where your user can choose from without typing anything.

You use [GetOleDbSchemaTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable(v=vs.110).aspx) from the OleDbConnection and fill a combo with a DropDownStyle of DropDownList

```
using(OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    excel_con.Open();
    DataTable result = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    var names = result.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME").TrimEnd('$')).ToList();
    comboBoxTables.DataSource = names;
}
```

Now your code could use the SelectedItem from the comboBoxTables and use the string concatenation approach without problems with Sql Injection.

Comment: At this point, the user doesn't have a choice about the sheet name (perhaps in the future), but I see where you are coming from, about the 'white list'. I'm going to look into this soon.

Comment: Well, then it is one of those exceptional situations where you could suppress the warning. The code analysis tool doesn't know that your string is safe. So, unless your tools' manufacturer adds more intelligence to the product, you will be forced to suppress or ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use code given below, user explicit provider declaration.

```
public System.Data.DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt, strig SheetName)
    {
        string conn = string.Empty;
        System.Data.DataTable dtexcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
        if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
            conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for below excel 2007  
        else
            conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"; //for above excel 2007  
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {
            try
            {
     String Query = String.Format("select * from [{0}]",SheetName);         
       // [sheet1] = [YouerSheetNameinExcelFile]
                //OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [sheet1]", con); //here we read data from sheet1  
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, con); //here we read data from sheet1 and from specific cell range.   
                oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel); //fill excel data into dataTable  
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
        return dtexcel;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the sheet name is coming from another class, so it can't be hard coded in.  Furthermore, this doesn't address the query parameters aspect of the question.